# What's the best strategy to diagnose/determine what is causing mixed-content warnings in your web application?

Tags: debugging, ssl

Is there some sort of profiling tool available?  View source and search/replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the message is usually a problem in IE, loading the page in Firefox with Firebug will let you see what is going on.

Also, you might find it helpful to leave the protocol off of the URLs in the first place: [Http-https transitions and relative URLs](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/httphttps_transitions_and_relative_urls.html).

Comment: What seems especially useful is the "Net" tab in FireBug.  It lists all the resources that are downloaded.  When you hover over one of the resources, it shows the protocol that was used during the download!

Answer (score 1):

I used view source which helps, although you might want to get a tool that lets you see the current source of the page like firebug in firefox.

One thing I ran into where this didn't help is if you have an iFrame in IE6 without a src attribute. IE6 will warn you about mixed content. No ammount of viewing source helped with this.

## Edit

Not sure why I didn't suggest this but you try using Fiddler? Or another packet sniffer? This should let you see ssl traffic, which might help you narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks Josh,

View source definitely seems useful for finding the great majority of the non https resources.  It doesn't help you find resources that are linked from other resources though.

Answer (score 0):

[WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) may also be of some help if you want something besides [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) for tools to try to resolve the issue.